# Display Context menu(<div>) component on windowed plugin

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, firebreath

Created a sample html page having firebreath windowed plugin loaded inside it.
My need is to display a div element overlapping over my plugin on click on plugin mousedown.
 Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't achieve that, the window plugin will overlap on any other html elements even you specify the z order of your plugin to be -1. We  work around this problem by using windowless plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can only participate in browser DOM z-order in a windowless plugin.